# Endless party… famous last words

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, music

Twelve of the clues are missing song titles, all different from one another, substituted by boldface question marks, one question mark per word. Each missing song was, as a single, in the top ten in [the U.K.](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Singles_Chart) or [the U.S.](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Hot_100) (or both). The twelve songs have something else also in common, as you'll discover in the course of solving the puzzle.

[image]

#### Across

**1.** Without a tee, golf better than, say, poop (6)
**4.** Drum and guitar innovator! (7)
**9.** Until **? ?** eats starters (3)
**10.** Style or theme: it can be proven (7)
**11.** A red metal penny is missing (3)
**12.** Table provided supper, after lunch was sent back (5)
**14.** In SoundCloud, "An Apostle" (4)
**16.** A cheese setback? (4)
**18.** Perhaps Princess Fiona returns without her ultimate self-esteem (3)
**19.** God of mourning (5)
**21.** Renal failure study (5)
**23.** Drummer's groin operated upon (5)
**24.** Governor of North Carolina and New York is fit (5)
**25. ? ? ?** at first: precisely when? (3)
**27.** For present, first of talkies follows moving picture (4)
**29.** Sergeant Major? (4)
**31.** Rank among fruit (5)
**33.** Endless party for a scripting language (3)
**34.** An anticoagulant, it's in a box (7)
**36. ? ?** message (as yet unknown) (3)
**37.** Speak to a **? ?**, perhaps? (7)
**38.** Eliot Canyon has echo (6)

#### Down

**1.** Supposed to arrive **?**, e.g., to ham it up for the audience (7)
**2. ? ? ?** lasts only part of a leg (3)
**3.** Say famous last words in reverse before king (5)
**4.** It's cold outside of Bangor! Taking a bit of rum (3)
**5. ? ?** with her head between her feet for a group of soldiers (4)
**6.** Perhaps was like a Princess Zelda melee (5)
**7.** Sleep among dugongs and manatees (7)
**8.** "Little **?** at last," cry (4)
**13.** Father now formed a glower (5)
**15.** Having an argument is high-class — not (5)
**17.** Develop **? ?** without an end (4)
**19.** Find uneven support (4)
**20.** Opening ration without a shake (5)
**22.** Moravians hide, maybe like magpies (5)
**23.** Objects, including crown, of grandeur! (7)
**26.** March: time for film (7)
**28.** A lie worded **? ? ? ?** (5)
**30. ? ? ?** with a bread (4)
**31.** Monsieur Gainsbourg's genre? Pah (5)
**32.** Top expert bored by Masonic initiation (4)
**35.** It's an insect, **? ?** (3)
**36.** Endless Story Hill (3)

Comment: Thanks to [Jafe](/u/41973) for [the idea](/q/110188).

Comment: Hah, I had rot13(Onatyrf) for 4a and couldn't figure what was wrong with it even after figuring out what the theme was... Nice puzzle!

Comment: Ugh, I just realized I shoulda combined the clues for 22 down and 23 down into one sentence with "…".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completed grid, with some relevant entries highlighted:

> [image]

Answers, **explanations**, clues with *song titles* inserted:

> **Across**
> 1a. OUTPUT **OUTPUT(-t)** Without a tee, golf better than, say, poop (6)
> 4a. BEATLES **BEAT + LES (Paul) &lit** Drum and guitar innovator! (7)
> 9a. ERE **first letters** Until *Eleanor Rigby* eats starters (3)
> 10a. THEOREM **ORTHEME*** Style or theme: it can be proven (7)
> 11a. ZIN **ZIN(-c)** A red metal penny is missing (3)
> 12a. DEFER **RE-FED<<** Table provided supper, after lunch was sent back (5)
> 14a. PAUL **homophone of PALL** In SoundCloud, "An Apostle" (4)
> 16a. EDAM **MADE<** A cheese setback? (4)
> 18a. EGO **OG(-r)E<** Perhaps Princess Fiona returns without her ultimate self-esteem (3)
> 19a. SHIVA **ddef** God of mourning (5)
> 21a. LEARN **RENAL*** Renal failure study (5)
> 23a. RINGO **GROIN*** Drummer's groin operated upon (5)
> 24a. TRY ON **ddef (William Tryon)** Governor of North Carolina and New York is fit (5)
> 25a. IFF **initial letters** *I Feel Fine* at first: precisely when? (3)
> 27a. GIFT **T follows GIF** For present, first of talkies follows moving picture (4)
> 29a. JOHN **first name of famous people called Sergeant and Major** Sergeant Major? (4)
> 31a. MANGO **AMONG*** Rank among fruit (5)
> 33a. LUA **LUA(-u)** Endless party for a scripting language (3)
> 34a. CITRATE **IT in CRATE** An anticoagulant, it's in a box (7)
> 36a. TBA **substring** *Get Back* message (as yet unknown) (3)
> 37a. ADDRESS? **A D DRESS** Speak to a *Day Tripper*, perhaps? (7)
> 38a. GEORGE **E in GORGE** Eliot Canyon has echo (6)
> **Down**
> 1d. OVERDUE **homophone of OVERDO** Supposed to arrive *Yesterday*, e.g., to ham it up for the audience (7)
> 2d. TOE **last letters** *Ticket to Ride* lasts only part of a leg (3)
> 3d. UTTER **(ET TU)< + R** Say famous last words in reverse before king (5)
> 4d. BRR **B(-ango)R + R(-um)** It's cold outside of Bangor! Taking a bit of rum (3)
> 5d. ARMY **MARY with M moved between R and Y** *Lady Madonna* with her head between her feet for a group of soldiers (4)
> 6d. LAZED **ZELDA*** Perhaps was like a Princess Zelda melee (5)
> 7d. SANDMAN **substring** Sleep among dugongs and manatees (7)
> 8d. WEEP **WEE + (-?)P** "Little *Help* at last," cry (4)
> 13d. FROWN **FR + NOW*** Father now formed a glower (5)
> 15d. UNARY **U+NARY** Having an argument is high-class — not (5)
> 17d. PLAN **P LAN(-e)** Develop *Penny Lane* without an end (4)
> 19d. SPOT **S(-u)P(-p)O(-r)T** Find uneven support (4)
> 20d. INTRO **R(-a)TION*** Opening ration without a shake (5)
> 22d. AVIAN **substring** Moravians hide, maybe like magpies (5)
> 23d. REGALIA **G in REALIA &lit** Objects, including crown, of grandeur! (7)
> 26d. FOOTAGE **FOOT+AGE** March: time for film (7)
> 28d. FRAUD **FRAMED with ME replaced by U** A lie worded *From Me To You* (5)
> 30d. NAAN **NAN containing A** *She's A Woman* with a bread (4)
> 31d. MYEYE **M + YE-YE** *but surely should be (2,3) not (5)* Monsieur Gainsbourg's genre? Pah (5)
> 32d. ACME **ACE containing M** Top expert bored by Masonic initiation (4)
> 35d. TIS **(-man)TIS** It's an insect, *Nowhere Man* (3)
> 36d. TOR **(-s)TOR(-y)** Endless Story Hill (3)

Credit and thanks where due:

> Jeremy Dover pointed out the intended song for 37a. (I had considered it but rejected it for the reasons above -- but Jeremy was *right*.) Jafe pointed out the right parsing of 12a, where I'd missed a key point. Jafe suggested the correct answer for 36a, which I hadn't considered; the song suggestion above is mine. msh210 kindly confirmed these people's suggestions, and also gave a hint for 28d.

Comment: For the 37A, I'm pretty sure the intended song/wordplay is rot13(Qnl Gevccre: N + Q (qnl) + QERFF (gevccre, creuncf?)).

Comment: I wondered about that exact parsing but I have no idea how rot13(QERFF = gevccre, creuncf).

Comment: In 12a "provided supper after lunch" could be just one word (the answer backwards)?

Comment: 36a's answer could also be rot13(GON = gb or naabhaprq = "nf lrg haxabja") although I haven't found a song title that makes it work...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about 31 down's enumeration. All the suggestions in the comments are what I intended (something that perhaps trips people).

Comment: Hint for 28 down: gur fbat gvgyr vf na vaqvpngbe, jung gb qb gb fbzrguvat pyhrq ol "jbeqrq".

Comment: I went through the whole list of songs yet again and finally figured out 28d. Duh.